# react hook setEmail giving error with no error message

Tags: reactjs

I have

```
const [setEmail, email] = useState();
```

though when I call setEmail("tom123412@hotmail.com") it does not setEmail and it does not give an error message

code

```
alert("before email - yes)

setEmail(tom123412@hotmail.com)

alert("after email - no)
```

`alert("after email - no)` never gets called? what the actual , no error message given either. and its not to do with @.com as when i call setEmail("sdsafs") it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

I think the way you are using the useState hook is wrong. What does useState return? It returns a pair of values: the current state and a function that updates it. This is why we write const [count, setCount] = useState().The order is important here. You have named them the other way. try below,

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState();
```

also refer https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html for how to use useState hook

Answer (score 0):

You should use `useState` hook properly. And it is not correct in the use of alert.

```
alert("before email - yes");
const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
alert("after email - no");
```